# c# windowphone 8.1 code with async task

Tags: c#, xml

i try to read xml form url.
this is my code:

```
static XDocument GetXml(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            return XDocument.Load(response.Result);
        }
    }
```

and i read xml like this:

```
public object DeteailsEmp(string emp_xml, string emp_error)
    {
        XDocument xml;
        try
        {
            xml = XDocument.Parse(GetXml(emp_xml).ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            xml = XDocument.Load(emp_error);
        }
        var detail = from query in xml.Descendants("emp")
                        select new Data.Emp
                        {
                            Name = (string)query.Element("name").Value,
                            Age = (string)query.Element("age").Value,
        return detail ;
    }
```

with this code, everything is ok.
but, when i change code to async task like this:

```
async static Task<XDocument> GetXml(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            return XDocument.Load(response);
        }
    }
```

i can't read xml with this code.
how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by can't read xml? Do you encounter an exception? If yes, post it. What does your DetailsEmp look like when you convert it to an asynchronous method?

Comment: The 2nd case where you are failing you are using response while the 1st case you are using response.Result().

Comment: @jdweng: because if i use response.Result(), it can't find Result()

Comment: @Ephraim: i just want change code to async task

Comment: @1234abcd your async version of GetXml is correct. How are you calling it?

Comment: @Ephraim : i just change GetXml() to async task, you can see it in my question. but when change it, it's not load emp_xml, it load emp_error. i think problem in GetXml() when change to async task, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ou mean it works without await but not with await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lazy earlier and didn't read the question properly. lol.

You forgot to call await on your DeteailsEmp method (Also it should be converted to async)

Call it like this:

```
object obj = await DeteailsEmp(param1, param2); // Proper call using await
```

or

```
object obj = DeteailsEmp(param1, param2).Result; // Force result



public async Task<object> DeteailsEmp(string emp_xml, string emp_error)
{
    XDocument xml;
    try
    {
        xml = XDocument.Parse((await GetXml(emp_xml)).ToString()); // Since GetXml is now an asynchronous method, you need to get the result first before calling ToString() or you can use GetXml(emp_xml).Result.ToString()
    }
    catch
    {
        xml = XDocument.Load(emp_error);
    }
    var detail = from query in xml.Descendants("emp")
                    select new Data.Emp
                    {
                        Name = (string)query.Element("name").Value,
                        Age = (string)query.Element("age").Value,
    return detail ;
}

async static Task<XDocument> GetXml(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
        return XDocument.Load(response);
    }
}
```